# DeviceIoControl ability to handle overlapped and non-overlapped handle?

Tags: windows, winapi, storage

Need to support handles opened **with and without** `FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED` in multi-threading environments.  I came up with the following, but wonder if there is a better way, especially if there was a way to reset the event on the file handle and wait again instead of spinning (even though I don't expect many conflicts)?

```
//
// Helper for device opened with or without FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED
//
static inline BOOL DeviceIoControlFlex(
  _In_        HANDLE       hdevice,
  _In_        DWORD        dwiocontrolcode,
  _In_opt_    LPVOID       lpinbuffer,
  _In_        DWORD        ninbuffersize,
  _Out_opt_   LPVOID       lpoutbuffer,
  _In_        DWORD        noutbuffersize,
  _Out_opt_   LPDWORD      lpbytesreturned,
  _Inout_opt_ LPOVERLAPPED lpoverlapped
)
{
  volatile OVERLAPPED overlapped={ 0 };

  BOOL diocresult=DeviceIoControl(hdevice,
                                  dwiocontrolcode,
                                  lpinbuffer,
                                  ninbuffersize,
                                  lpoutbuffer,
                                  noutbuffersize,
                                  lpbytesreturned,
                                  lpoverlapped ? lpoverlapped : (LPOVERLAPPED) &overlapped);

  // complete operation synchronously if opened in overlapped mode
  if (!diocresult && GetLastError()==ERROR_IO_PENDING) {
    // check if we wait
    if (lpoverlapped==NULL) {
      DWORD bytesreturned=0;
      diocresult=GetOverlappedResult(hdevice, (LPOVERLAPPED) &overlapped, &bytesreturned, TRUE);
      // make sure actually completed since waiting on file handle.  If not spin
      if (overlapped.Internal==STATUS_PENDING) {
        while (overlapped.Internal==STATUS_PENDING) {
          CPUPAUSE;
        }
        bytesreturned=overlapped.InternalHigh;
        if (!NT_SUCCESS((NTSTATUS)overlapped.Internal)) {
          diocresult=FALSE;
          SetLastError(RtlNtStatusToDosError((NTSTATUS)overlapped.Internal));
        }
        else diocresult=TRUE;
      }
      // handle optional bytes to return       
      if (lpbytesreturned) {
        *lpbytesreturned=bytesreturned;
      }
    }
  }

  return diocresult;
}
```

Note: This actually may not work depending on how`GetOverlappedResult` is handled internally, if it obtains the byte count prior to checking the results it possible the byte count returned is wrong (completed just after that field was accessed).

TIA!!

Comment: *reset the event on the file handle* - you not need care about this internal at all
for what you declare overlapped as volatile ? for what you use local overlapped at all ?
after GetOverlappedResult return with wait set to TRUE - `overlapped.Internal!=STATUS_PENDING` - so all next code senseless
anyway, as separate note - GetOverlappedResult already set last error, if io fail, by translate overlapped.Internal
RtlNtStatusToDosError already set last error too, so SetLastError 2 time senseless here
so all code bad and must not be used

Comment: if you do io on asynchronous file handle - you **must** pass pointer to `OVERLAPPED`. if you use synchronous file handle - you not need use overlapped here (can but not need). unclear at all what you try todo

Comment: You can use [Wait Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sync/wait-functions) to wait the IO complete and hang-up the thread, instead of spinning.

Comment: You seem worry about DeviceIoControlFlex function if it is thread-safe?

Comment: @RitaHan-MSFT - but in code and used wait function `GetOverlappedResult`. however all code is wrong

Comment: This busy wait you've implemented is wasteful. If you have a file object opened in asynchronous mode, set a per-thread event object in `overlapped` in order for `GetOverlappedResult` to reliably wait for I/O completion. If you want to skip using `overlapped` in synchronous mode, you can call `NtQueryInformationFile`: `FileModeInformation` and check for `FILE_SYNCHRONOUS_IO_NONALERT`.

Comment: IMO, avoid thinking in terms of "handles ... with ... `FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED`" and the "event on the file handle". A handle is an opaque reference to a kernel object that has attributes and the granted access. We're talking about a [File object](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/wdm/ns-wdm-_file_object). A File object is a special object type in NT, since we create one by opening a Device. It's also special because it may share state with other File objects, i.e. all File objects that reference the same file in a filesystem share an FCB as their `FsContext`.

Comment: I think the point is being missed.  This is a generic routine that doesn't know how the handle was opened.  It just needs to work in multi-threaded environments.  The main thing being supported here is if opened in overlapped mode, but user doesn't provide overlap structure, which means I need to complete synchronously.  If I create and close an event on each request, it seems there would be a lot of overhead. So it just waits on the handle (if overlapped mode of course).  In which case the `GetOverlappedResult` could return early if another thread had an item complete on the same handle. ...

Comment: ... So I must check the status of the io completion (overlapped) to see if it's actually done, if not, wait for it.  But I'd rather not spin, maybe it will allow me to ResetEvent() on the handle myself and then I could wait again on it?

Comment: *if opened in overlapped mode, but user doesn't provide overlap structure* - user must provide overlapped in this case. for what you at all open files in asynchronous mode, if really want synchronous processing ? if wait on overlapped - here must be event, otherwise code is wrong. all after *GetOverlappedResult* in your code complete senseless

Comment: The user to the interface doesn't need to provide anything, that's what I have to handle, I have no clue how the handle was opened.  Sending my own overlapped structure in case user didn't provide one is fine but it waits on handle (I could `CreateEvent()` each time but that may be too slow, especially in read/write routines.  I could also provide a pre-created Event, but then I have to protect it with something like a Mutex).

Comment: @user3161924 If `lpOverlappedI` is `NULL` you can assume the handle opened without `FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED` then the function does not return until the operation has been completed or an error occurs. Otherwise `DeviceIoControl` returns immediately, and the event object is signaled when the operation has been completed. So you can use wait function, for example, [`WaitForSingleObject`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-registerwaitforsingleobject).

Comment: I can't assume that, if it's not provided, it's just one of the 100's of other routines deep in the library that presume opened sync mode.  They won't know what the process/app did, they just get a handle (from an object), so I need to handle within the lower level support routine.   If the original win api would handle NULL `OVERLAPPED` structure even if opened with `FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED` would make things easy, but as far as I know, that's not the case?  My code above works, already tested, but it does have to spin for short period of times.

Comment: @user3161924, I did not tell you to create an event for each `DeviceIoControlFlex` call. I suggested using a per-thread event object. You would create it once and access it as a thread-local variable.